# IOS: how to get the value of a single key from dictionary

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I have a dictionary which is in the form of I want to get the value of "id"

```
{
  "procedures": [5950]
   0:  {
   "Procedures": {
                  "id": "1"
                  "procedure_name": "3d render w/o postprocess"
                  "procedure_code": "76376"
                 }
       }
  1:  {
        "Procedures": {
        "id": "2"
        "procedure_name": "3d rendering w/postprocess"
        "procedure_code": "76377"
 }
```

all I want to get the value of "id"
how I get this value

I put the following code

```
NSString *post = @"api_key=............";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:........"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSDictionary *dict6 = [self cleanJsonToObject:responseData];
```

Comment: Plz give some more info... do you want all id's or particular id?

Comment: yes i want id only in dictionary form

Comment: can you show your full response ....

Comment: it comes in an array which have 5940 elements so its not possible to show full responce

Answer (score 1):

Try following code..

```
NSArray *ids = [[dict6 objectForKey:@"procedures"] valueForKeyPath:@"Procedures.id"];
```

or

```
NSArray *ids = [[dict6 objectForKey:@"procedures"] valueForPath:@"id"];
```

Comment: check "dict6" is not null

Comment: it gives result but i didn't find the exact result

Comment: thats why I asked to give more info.. what id you want to fetch.. what is criteria..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as it is nested NSDictionary.

```
[[[dict6 objectForKey:@"0"] objectForKey:@"Procedures"] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Comment: it gives null output